# Can an ImageCollection contain a single image?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I found about GEE yesterday and found an interesting dataset (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_ORNL_biomass_carbon_density_v1) about biomass during 2010. I am fairly new at programming so maybe I am missing something, but I believe this dataset is actually just a single image.

I ran the below code and it's output appears to return just a single image data, whereas with other datasets using the same procedure several images's data was provided.

Assuming I am right, I am a bit confused because the dataset is suppose to reflect data for all 2010. Should I considered this single image data as an average over that year? Is there a way to sample this ImageCollection?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
images = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/ORNL/biomass_carbon_density/v1").select(['agb'])
images.getInfo()['features'] 

[{'type': 'Image',
  'bands': [{'id': 'agb',
    'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'float'},
    'dimensions': [129600, 64800],
    'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
    'crs_transform': [0.002777777777777778,
     0,
     -180,
     0,
     -0.002777777777777778,
     90]}],
  'version': 1594761247408801,
  'id': 'NASA/ORNL/biomass_carbon_density/v1/2010',
  'properties': {'system:footprint': {'type': 'LinearRing',
    'coordinates': [[-180, -90],
     [180, -90],
     [180, 90],
     [-180, 90],
     [-180, -90]]},
   'system:asset_size': 21951251143,
   'system:index': '2010'}}]
```

Comment: @Kevin Reid Thanks for the confirmation and advice! Surely will ask there.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the dataset contains exactly one image. This prints `1`:

```js
print(ee.ImageCollection("NASA/ORNL/biomass_carbon_density/v1").size());
```

Questions about the interpretation of the data might be best asked over at [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).